# *jade* precompile templates to use in the next time

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, compilation, pug

I need to precompile the function to compile a jade template.
After, I will can use eval() to compile this function with the local options specified.

Theorically, I have found in the source jade.compileClient (previously called as options.client) but calling this function raises an unexpected error saying "jade is not defined"

code example:

```
precompiled = "[" + jade.compileClient(source, {filename: myFilenameExample}) + "]";
fn = eval(precompiled)[0]; //compilation
html = fn(options); //execution
```

Same problem with Handlebars using handlebars.precompile()  :'(

No problems, instead, with EJS using ejs.compile({client: true})

Comment: compileClient is supposed to be used on the client-side with [jade runtime](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/runtime.js)

Comment: ok :( but it's impossible that does not exists a way to compile the function to a file :(

Comment: It does exist. But you have to add jade runtime on top of that file.

Comment: already tried with same errors, maybe I'm wrong something, can you provide an example ? (remember, I'm in server side)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is how you can bundle jade with your template:

```
$ echo 'var jade = (function() { var exports={};' > build.js
$ cat node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js >> build.js
$ echo 'return exports;})();' >> build.js
$ jade -c -D < template.jade >> build.js 
$ echo 'console.log(template({}))' >> build.js
$ node build.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand your question. But it seems like this would do what you want:

```
var _jade = require('jade');
var template = process.cwd() + '/views/index.jade';

// get template from file system
fs.readFile(template, 'utf8', function(err, file){
  if(err){
    //handle errors
    console.log('ERROR!');
    return res.send('ERROR!');
  }
  else {
    //compile jade template into function
    var compiledTmpl = _jade.compile(file, {filename: template});
    // set context to be used in template
    var context = {title: 'Express'};
    // get html back as a string with the context applied;
    var html = compiledTmpl(context);
    // do something with html
  }
});
```

Comment: In this way you cannot save the compiled function, I need to save as string exactly the function to create the compiled function